# Why can't I find my profile by querying in the Stack Exchange (data explorer)

Tags: sql, stackexchange, dataexplorer

I am trying to get information regarding my profile in Stack Overflow. I tried querying after an hour of opening my account in Stack Overflow but I still can't find my account.

The following is my query

```
Select * from Users where DisplayName= 'Maliha Mahbub'
```

Comment: I would assume you simply have to wait longer; I can't query against your user, but can query against myself. Perhaps there's some other limit in play too, like reputation. Either way, this should be asked on the [**StackExchange META**](https://meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: `[dataexplorer]` questions are allowed here (although there is some gray area and meta overlap), and the OP doesn't have enough rep to post on Meta.

Answer (score 1):

You can't see your info in the Data Explorer yet because [you joined Stack Overflow on 2018‑10‑31](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10583351/maliha-mahbub?tab=profile), but the Explorer data was [last updated on 2018-10-28](https://data.stackexchange.com/):

[image: SEDE update time]

**Data Explorer (SEDE) data is updated once a week.**  Check back on November 4th.

Meanwhile, you can see your account in the API:

[/2.2/users?&inname=Maliha Mahbub&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users#order=desc&sort=reputation&inname=Maliha%20Mahbub&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

Which is updated in real time.